# How do you build depended-upon libs before the main project with CMake in Qt?

Tags: qt, cmake, cmakelists-options

I've looked at similar questions but haven't found one for this basic scenario. I'm relatively new to CMake. I have a CMake-based Qt 5 project. It's a simple test application; during its build I want to build and statically link the open-source Paho MQTT C lib and the C++ wrapper for it. Those are two separate projects with their own CMakeLists.txt files.

Per Qt's default, it builds into a directory outside the source tree.

I've copied the source trees for these open-source libs under the parent directory of my project, and edited the top-level CMakeLists.txt file to add_subdirectory them.

I also added target_link_libraries. I can get the C lib by itself to build and link into the parent project, but if I add the C++ wrapper, the processing for the C++ wrapper complains that it can't find the C lib... which is true because it hasn't been built yet. A similar complaint for the C lib was solved by simply using Qt's "build all projects" menu item, but that doesn't work when the C++ wrapper lib is added. The wrapper's CMakeLists.txt files issues this:

> CMake Error at paho.mqtt.cpp/src/CMakeLists.txt:150 (message):
> Could not find Paho MQTT C library

And sure enough it doesn't exist because it has not been built when this preprocessing is done.

UPDATED: Here's my top-level CMakeLists.txt file, revised per Corristo's suggestion, which was successful in getting CMake to parse the entire hierarchy. The project now builds. I'm perplexed that the last two lines here result in an empty string, though. So does a similar attempt for the link directories.

```
find_package(QT NAMES Qt6 Qt5 COMPONENTS Widgets REQUIRED)
find_package(Qt${QT_VERSION_MAJOR} COMPONENTS Widgets REQUIRED)

set(PROJECT_SOURCES
        main.cpp
        mainwindow.cpp
        mainwindow.h
        mainwindow.ui
    task.h
    task.cpp
    task.ui
)

if(${QT_VERSION_MAJOR} GREATER_EQUAL 6)
    qt_add_executable(MQTTTest
        ${PROJECT_SOURCES}
    )
else()
    if(ANDROID)
        add_library(MQTTTest SHARED
            ${PROJECT_SOURCES}
        )
    else()
        add_executable(MQTTTest
            ${PROJECT_SOURCES}
        )
    endif()
endif()

add_subdirectory(paho.mqtt.c)
set(PAHO_MQTT_C_LIB paho-mqtt3a)
set(PAHO_MQTT_C_PATH "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/paho.mqtt.c")
add_subdirectory(paho.mqtt.cpp)

target_link_libraries(MQTTTest PRIVATE Qt${QT_VERSION_MAJOR}::Widgets)
target_link_directories(MQTTTest PUBLIC
                        "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/build/paho.mqtt.c/src"
                        "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/build/paho.mqtt.cpp/src")

target_link_libraries(MQTTTest PUBLIC paho-mqtt3a)
target_link_libraries(MQTTTest PUBLIC paho-mqttpp3)

target_include_directories(MQTTTest PUBLIC
                        "${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}"
                        "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/paho.mqtt.c/src"
                        "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/paho.mqtt.cpp/src")

get_property(inc_dirs DIRECTORY PROPERTY INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES)
message("Top-level include dirs = ${inc_dirs}")
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a bit of a hack, but you can use the fact that the CMake `find_*` commands don't perform a search if the result variable is already set.

From the `paho.mqtt.cpp/src/CMakeLists.txt` file we find that the output variable for `find_library` is called `PAHO_MQTT_C_LIB` and the include directory is expected to be in `PAHO_MQTT_C_INC_DIR`, which in the [original CMakeLists.txt from version 1.0.0](https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.cpp/blob/v1.0.0/src/CMakeLists.txt) (which seems to be the version you're using) is itself computed from `PAHO_MQTT_C_PATH`.

Setting these two variables between the two `add_subdirectory` calls should then make this work:

```
add_subdirectory(paho.mqtt.c)
set(PAHO_MQTT_C_LIB paho-mqtt3a)
set(PAHO_MQTT_C_PATH "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/paho.mqtt.c")
add_subdirectory(paho.mqtt.cpp)
```

This makes use of the fact that `target_link_libraries` can be called both with library files (which is what the original paho.mqtt.cpp project expected) and with existing CMake targets (which is what we replaced it with). Linking to a CMake target also automatically introduces a build-order dependency, so this simultaneously ensures that the c library is built before the cpp library.

However, since this relies on the names of the variables used in the `paho.mqtt.cpp` project as well as the target name of the library target in the `paho.mqtt.c` project this can break any time you update one of these libraries to a newer version.

Comment: That's great, thanks! It seems to have me most of the way there. Now I have a problem of compilation failing with a header file not found. In the top-level CMakeLists.txt, I'm providing include directories. But retrieving the INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES property right after that with get_property and printing them out shows it's empty. I'll edit my question so I can post this info. Thanks again, great help.

Comment: BTW, if this is a "hacky" way, what's the non-hacky solution, I wonder.

Comment: @Oscar: There isn't any non-hacky solution yet, but there are discussions on the CMake issue-tracker about providing a way to integrate `FetchContent` (i.e. building from sources`) with `find_package`/`find_library` which currently only searches for binaries and which is used here, too.

Comment: *I'm perplexed that the last two lines here result in an empty string, though.* There are multiple ways to set the include directories, the directory property you're querying is only one of them (which is unused in this case). You could e.g. read the `INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES` and `INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES` target properties of the `MQTTTest` target, they shouldn't both be empty.

Comment: Thanks. I also tested the INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES a few lines above, in the same way, and also got an empty string.

Comment: @Oscar That also is not surprising: You only link `PUBLIC`ly in your `target_link_library` calls, so all interface include directories of the targets you link against populate the `INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES` property. If you were to link `PRIVATE`ly against eg. `paho-mqttpp3` you should see the include dir of the C++ mqtt library show up in `INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES`.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't gather this from the documentation, and attempting to look up its use of "interface" didn't reveal what it meant in that context vs. "public." However, I just tried INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES in that second-to-last line and still got nothing.

Comment: @Oscar: To avoid misunderstanding, you are checking the directory property or the target property? You should see include directories when using `get_property(inc_dirs TARGET MQTTTest PROPERTY INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES)` (or, alternatively, `get_target_property(inc_dirs MQTTTest INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES)`), unless the paho mqtt libraries do not set `target_include_directories` themselves, which they should

Comment: Thanks. I don't understand your question about "directory property" vs. "target property." I'm just talking about the last few lines of my CMakeLists.txt file above (which is the highest-level CMakeLists.txt). I call target_include_directories with several paths, and I expect to see those paths in the subsequent get_property(inc_dirs DIRECTORY PROPERTY INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES).

Comment: @Oscar: CMake allows to set properties on a variety of different objects (individual source files, targets, entire directories and global properties). Include paths can be set for directories, targets and source files, and what is used for the compilation of a particular source file is the combination of these. Your `get_property(.. DIRECTORY ..)` call queries the directory property of the current directory, which is unset. The target property on the other hand should've been populated by the `target_link_libraries` calls which propagates `PUBLIC`/`INTERFACE` include directories to consumers.

Comment: Thanks. Didn't the previous line set include paths on the current directory as well? Why would the set command act on one object, but the subsequent query in the next line act on another?

Comment: @Oscar: No, `target_include_directories` sets target properties. `include_directories` sets the directory property.

Comment: Ah, so I need to use get_target_property instead of get_property.

Comment: @Oscar: You can use `get_target_property`, or `get_property(... TARGET MQTTTest ...)`.